# Как откорректировать работу js скрипта для модульного окна

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, ruby-on-rails, ruby

я новичок в js и передо мной стоит задача сделать появление модального окна при нажатии на кнопку. Я написал вьюху для постов и добавил к ней кнопку и скрипт для отображения модального окна, взятые с [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp). Получилось что-то в роде

```
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="leftcolumn">
          <div class="card">
        <h2 lang="ru"><%= post.title %></h2>
        <p lang="ru"><%= post.body %></p>
        <button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button> <!-- взято с сайта -->

        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal">

          <!-- Modal content -->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <p><%= post.translation %></p>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>

<script>
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
    btn.onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function (event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Всё работает прекрасно, но... только для самого первого поста... Скрипт обрабатывает только самую первую кнопку. Я, кажется, знаю, почему такое происходит, но как это исправить- не в моих силах. Мне кажется, что всё происходит от того, что здесь берётся getElementById при создании переменных. В общем, я буду очень благодарен, если Вы мне поможете, спасибо.

Comment: Вы правы, ошибка в  `document.getElementById("myBtn")`. Решение - нет простого решения, надо менять и html код и js код. Для начала - вынесите модальное окно из цикла. Затем читайте про `document.querySelectorAll`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На странице не должно быть элементов с одинаковыми `id`, поэтому убираем атрибуты `id` у кнопки открытия и модального окна.

На мой взгляд лучше использовать `data-` атрибуты.
Для кнопки открытия, кнопки закрытия и модального окна добавляет атрибуты `data-id=<%= post.id %>`

Т.к. кнопок и окон много, то нужно для них всех определить функцию `onclick`, а для этого нужно сначала выбрать их все, например для кнопки открытия - `var btns = document.getElementsByClassName( "myBtn" );`.
И уже в цикле добавляем для них обработчики события:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++ ) {
  var btn = btns[ i ];
  btn.onclick = function () {
    var modal = document.querySelector("div.modal[data-id=\"" + this.dataset.id + "\"]" );
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modal.classList.add( "visible" );
  };
}
```

Здесь мы уже выбираем нужное нам окно по `data-` атрибуту - здесь `this` это кнопка открытия. "Показываем" его. И добавляем класс `visible` - это для того, чтобы потом проще было определить какое окно открыто.

```js
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName( "myBtn" );
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName( "close" );
for ( var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++ ) {
  var btn = btns[ i ];
  btn.onclick = function (event) {
    var modal = document.querySelector( "div.modal[data-id=\"" + this.dataset.id + "\"]" );
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modal.classList.add( "visible" );
  };
}
for ( var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++ ) {
  var span = spans[ i ];
  span.onclick = function (event) {
    var modal = document.querySelector( "div.modal[data-id=\"" + this.dataset.id + "\"]" );
    modal.style.display = "none";
    modal.classList.remove( "visible" );
  };
}
```

```css
div.modal {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="leftcolumn">
    <div class="card">
      <h2 lang="ru">post.title 1</h2>
      <p lang="ru">post.body 1</p>
      <button class="myBtn" data-id="1">Open Modal</button>
      <div class="modal" data-id="1">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <span class="close" data-id="1">&times;</span>
          <p>post.translation 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="leftcolumn">
    <div class="card">
      <h2 lang="ru">post.title 2</h2>
      <p lang="ru">post.body 2</p>
      <button class="myBtn" data-id="2">Open Modal</button>
      <div class="modal" data-id="2">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <span class="close" data-id="2">&times;</span>
          <p>post.translation</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```